# React table with sorting and pagination doesn't update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, datatable, pagination

I am making a simple table in react where I have pagination (separate component) and sorting.

The table should sort update when table header is clicked. It changes state of data. The data is sorted but it doesn't update. The table is rerendered when I change page (pagination component) and it does have sorted data. 
The problem is with

```
 this.state.pageOfItems.map((element, index) =>
```

if I change it to

```
 this.state.data.map((element, index) =>
```

then sorting works, but pagination doesn't

Please help me get the table data updated immidiately when table header is clicked.

**Table component:**

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';

    import classes from './Table.css';
    import data from 'data.json';
    import Pagination from '../Pagination/Pagination';

    class Table extends Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        data: props.data,
        headings: Object.keys(props.data[0]),
        sortOrder: props.sortOrder || "original",
        sortKey: props.sortKey || null,
        pageOfItems: []
      };
      this.sortHandler = this.sortHandler.bind(this);
      this.onChangePage = this.onChangePage.bind(this);

    }

    componentWillMount() {
      //TODO: only apply this to the root element of the table component
      document.addEventListener('dragover', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
      });
    }

    sortHandler(e){
      const sortKey = e.target.dataset.sortcolumn;
      const currentSortKey = this.state.sortKey;
      const currentSortOrder = (sortKey === currentSortKey) ? this.state.sortOrder : "original";
      this.setState({sortKey: e.target.dataset.sortcolumn});
      console.log(currentSortOrder)
      switch(currentSortOrder){
        case "original":
        this.setState({sortOrder: "ascending"});
        this.state.data.sort((a, b)=>{
          if (a[sortKey] < b[sortKey]) {
            return -1;
          }
          if (a[sortKey] > b[sortKey]) {
            return 1;
          }
          return 0;
        });
        break;
        case "ascending":
        this.setState({sortOrder: "descending"});
        this.state.data.sort((a, b)=>{
          if (a[sortKey] < b[sortKey]) {
            return 1;
          }
          if (a[sortKey] > b[sortKey]) {
            return -1;
          }
          return 0;
        });
        break;
        case "descending":
        this.setState({sortOrder: "original"});
        this.state.data = this.props.data;
        break;
      }
      this.setState({data: this.state.data});
      console.log(this.state.data);
    }

    onChangePage(pageOfItems) {
      // update state with new page of items
      this.setState({ pageOfItems: pageOfItems });
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div role="region" aria-labelledby={this.props.id} tabindex="0" style={{overflow: 'auto'}}>
        <table cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" data-sortorder={this.state.sortOrder}>
        {this.props.caption &&
          <caption id={this.props.id}>{this.props.caption}</caption>
        }
        <thead>
        <tr>
        {this.state.headings.map((element, index) => {
          return (
            <th
            data-sortcolumn={element}
            id={'header' + index}
            onClick={this.sortHandler}>
            {element}
            </th>
          )
        })}
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {this.state.pageOfItems.map((element, index) => {
          return (
            <tr
            id={'row' + index}>
            {element && Object.values(element).map((cell)=>{
              return <td>
              {cell}
              </td>
            })}
            </tr>
          )
        })}
        </tbody>
        </table>
        <Pagination items={this.state.data} onChangePage={this.onChangePage} />
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

**Pagination component:**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const propTypes = {
    items: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    onChangePage: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    initialPage: PropTypes.number
}

const defaultProps = {
    initialPage: 1
}

class Pagination extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { pager: {} };
}

componentWillMount() {
    this.setPage(this.props.initialPage);
}

setPage(page) {
    var items = this.props.items;
    var pager = this.state.pager;

    if (page < 1 || page > pager.totalPages) {
        return;
    }

    // get new pager object for specified page
    pager = this.getPager(items.length, page);

    // get new page of items from items array
    var pageOfItems = items.slice(pager.startIndex, pager.endIndex + 1);

    // update state
    this.setState({ pager: pager });

    // call change page function in parent component
    this.props.onChangePage(pageOfItems);
}

getPager(totalItems, currentPage, pageSize) {
    // default to first page
    currentPage = currentPage || 1;

    // default page size is 10
    pageSize = pageSize || 5;

    // calculate total pages
    var totalPages = Math.ceil(totalItems / pageSize);

    var startPage, endPage;
    if (totalPages <= 10) {
        // less than 10 total pages so show all
        startPage = 1;
        endPage = totalPages;
    } else {
        // more than 10 total pages so calculate start and end pages
        if (currentPage <= 6) {
            startPage = 1;
            endPage = 10;
        } else if (currentPage + 4 >= totalPages) {
            startPage = totalPages - 9;
            endPage = totalPages;
        } else {
            startPage = currentPage - 5;
            endPage = currentPage + 4;
        }
    }

    // calculate start and end item indexes
    var startIndex = (currentPage - 1) * pageSize;
    var endIndex = Math.min(startIndex + pageSize - 1, totalItems - 1);

    // create an array of pages to ng-repeat in the pager control
    var pages = [...Array((endPage + 1) - startPage).keys()].map(i => startPage + i);

    // return object with all pager properties required by the view
    return {
        totalItems: totalItems,
        currentPage: currentPage,
        pageSize: pageSize,
        totalPages: totalPages,
        startPage: startPage,
        endPage: endPage,
        startIndex: startIndex,
        endIndex: endIndex,
        pages: pages
    };
}

render() {
    var pager = this.state.pager;

    return (
        <ul className="pagination">
            <li className={pager.currentPage === 1 ? 'disabled' : ''}>
                <a onClick={() => this.setPage(pager.currentPage - 1)}>&lt; back</a>
            </li>
            {pager.pages.map((page, index) =>
                <li key={index} className={pager.currentPage === page ? 'active' : ''}>
                    <a onClick={() => this.setPage(page)}>{page}</a>
                </li>
            )}
            <li className={pager.currentPage === pager.totalPages ? 'disabled' : ''}>
                <a onClick={() => this.setPage(pager.currentPage + 1)}>next &gt;</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    );
}
}

Pagination.propTypes = propTypes;
Pagination.defaultProps
export default Pagination;
```

EDIT: A part of the pagination has been moved to table component and now it works correctly

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may come from the fact that you try changing `this.state` directly in your method `sortHandler` before passing it to `setState`.

Try cloning `this.state.data` first: `var clone = this.state.data.slice(0);`

Then manipulate (`sort`) it, and finally assign it to your new state with `this.setState({ data: clone })`

Also, you may avoid calling multiple times `this.setState()` in your method, rather once at then end of your function.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried it, but unfortunately the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

I found several problems here.

First: don't assign state by `this.state['arg']=`. It's a bad practice. Use `this.setState()` instead.

Second: `this.setState()` it's asynchronous function, don't forget. Use callbacks. `this.setState({ data }, () => anotherFunction())`

In your case you can use lodash `cloneDeep()` method. It return deep copy of object, so you will not change original object. `const data = _.cloneDeep(this.state.data).sort()`.

So. `this.setState({ sortKey: e.target.dataset.sortcolumn }, () => putYourSwitchHere());` After that,

```
      this.setState({sortOrder: "ascending"});
        this.state.data.sort((a, b)=>{
          if (a[sortKey] < b[sortKey]) {
            return -1;
          }
          if (a[sortKey] > b[sortKey]) {
            return 1;
          }
          return 0;
        });
        break;
```

Try to use:

```
        const data = _.cloneDeep(this.state.data).sort((a, b)=>{
          if (a[sortKey] < b[sortKey]) {
            return -1;
          }
          if (a[sortKey] > b[sortKey]) {
            return 1;
          }
          return 0;
        });
   this.setState({sortOrder: "ascending", data});
   break;
```

You have already assign `this.state.data`, `this.state.data = this.props.data` will make a lot of errors in your last case.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `sortHandler` function.

You are sorting the data using javascript `sort()` method. It is mutating method and doesn't create new object so React.js can't detect that the data has changed.

You should use non-mutating method.

Your code should be

```
const newData = this.state.data.concat().sort(...); 
this.setState({data: newData});
```